# Do these two definitions of *enough projectives* coincide?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a $k$-linear abelian category. Are the following two definitions of **enough projectives** equivalent?

> (i) For every object $A$ there exists a projective object $P$ s.t. $P\twoheadrightarrow A$
>
> (ii) Every simple object $U_i$ has a projective cover $p_i: P_i\twoheadrightarrow U_i$

The first one is taken from wikipedia, the second from the book *Tensor Categories* by Etingof *et al*.

I think this cannot be the same, for the superficial reason that nothing in *(ii)* makes a reference to arbitrary (generally indecomposable) objects of $\mathcal{C}$. However, I might be very wrong since I cannot seem to prove it.

Any pointers?

Comment: What's your definition of simple object?

Comment: One whose only subobjects are $0$ and itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not, in general. I bet Etingof is assuming we're in a semisimple category, as is usually the case, if not always, in that book. If every object is a sum of simples, then it should be clear that these conditions are equivalent, since a sum of projectives is projective and a sum of epis is epi. The conditions are not equivalent in general, since abelian categories need not have any simple objects. See Jeremy Rickard's example  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269120/semisimple-objects-in-abelian-categories/).

Comment: To be fair, I lied a bit (by omission). We are actually assuming *local finiteness* (Hom-finite and every object has finite length) and finitely many iso classes of simple objects. As you might have noticed, this is precisely the definition of a finite abelian cat over $k$, which is generally not semisimple.

Comment: If the category is semsimple, then the statement is trivial: all objects are projective in this case!

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the local finiteness assumption in your comment to Kevin Arlin's answer (which should rather be in the question itself), here is the receipe to treat a general object, assuming (ii): consider its head (quotient by the radical, which is semisimple), and take the direct sum of the projective covers of the simples involved.